# cannot run flutter snap

Tags: flutter, ubuntu-20.04, snap

I just installed Flutter on Ubuntu 20.04 through the snapstore

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

However, after the installation is complete if I run this command in the console (or any other including `flutter`)

```
flutter
```

I get this errors

```
Initializing Flutter
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0     48      0  0:00:04  0:00:03  0:00:01    48
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
[.releases[] | select(.hash==)][0].archive
jq: 1 compile error
Downloading /
curl: (3) <url> malformed
tar: latest_stable.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Flutter initialization failed
Could not find working copy of Flutter
```

Comment: Any update about it? I'm having the same problem with my flutter installation. I'll appreciate any help, please!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Adrian. You can try to run it from the path provided from:

```
flutter sdk-path
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).